# PDFBox getFontSize returns -1

Tags: java, pdfbox, text-extraction

I am using `PDFbox` to get the font size from PDFs.

I have extended `PDFTextStripper` and overridden the `writeString` function which gives me access to `TextPosition` object.

It works fine half the time. But the other times it returns font size as '-1'. Why is that? This affects the rest of my algorithm.

I have tried functions `getHeight`, `getHeightDir` and `getFontSize`. I get the same results with all these.

Here is the `writeString` function:

```
@Override
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
    for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
        getChar(text);
        writeString(string);
    }
}
```

The `getChar` function processes the information.

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I'm using PDFBox 2.0.2. My application requires me to convert any given file to a pdf and then process it using PDFBox. This -1 problem happens to all Spreadsheet files. I use Apache POI 3.15 to convert the document to PDF. It works fine for doc, docx, ppt, pptx, odt, odp

Comment: Please share your pdf and mention what version you are using

Comment: I'm using PDFBox 2.0.2. 
My application requires me to convert any given file to a pdf and then process it using PDFBox. This -1 problem happens to all Spreadsheet files.

I use Apache POI 3.15 to convert the document to PDF.

It works fine for doc, docx, ppt, pptx, odt, odp.

Comment: Current version is 2.0.6. I can only have a look at the problem if you share a PDF. If you don't, try the PrintTextLocations example and see what getFontSize() returns.

Comment: Please do as Tilman asks you. Only telling vaguely how one could create the PDFs, is not sensible. Please simply supply a sample PDF.

Comment: @SidPrasad If your files are confidential, then create a non confidential spreadsheet file and convert that one.

Comment: @SidPrasad Please be precise in asking your questions, and you cant just leave unanswered comments, Please Respond otherwise I will have to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared a sample document, from your question, here are my inferences.

Assuming PDFBox works fine, if getFontSize returns -1, then font size has not been set at the source side, i.e., while generating the PDF. If from your observation, the characters for which getFontSize returns -1 has all the same size, this could be thought of as a **default size**.

If this does not help, for an actual solution, you may provide any sample pdf, as mentioned in the comments by others.